# APK versionName grep

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Im trying to retrieve the VersionName of a bunch of apk files i have in different folders and store them in an array , but its not working ...
I've tried pretty much everything but it only loops 1 time/stops after 1rst APK file.

```
for folders in */ ; 

  do cd $source${MAP[android]}/$folders

  version=("$(aapt dump badging * | grep versionName )") && echo Entering into $folders and getting versionName

done ;

echo ${version[*]};
```

i get this :

package: name='myapp' versionCode='47' versionName='1.9' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2438415'

and only

```
${version[0]}
```

is used...

**EDIT** : thanks to steeldriver help , I was able to now get all versionName  but all of them are stored in ${version[0]}...

```
for folders in */ ; 

  do cd $source${MAP[android]}/$folders

  version+=("$(aapt dump badging * | grep versionName )") && echo Entering into $folders and getting versionName

done ;

echo ${version[*]};
```

**output :**
package: name='app' versionCode='48' versionName='1.10' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2438415'package: name='app' versionCode='53' versionName='1.11' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2438415'package: name='app' versionCode='47' versionName='1.9' platformBuildVersionName='6.0-2438415'

Comment: Are you sure they are all in a single element? `echo ${version[*]}` isn't the best way to tell that, since it outputs a space-separated list. Have you actually looked at individual elements by index e.g. `echo "${version[1]}"`?

Comment: It's working now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to append successive outputs of a command substitution to an array in `bash`, you can use a syntax like

```
arr+=( "$(command args)" )
```

For example, give files with

```
$ grep -H 'versionName' thing*
thing1:versionName: foo
thing2:versionName: bar
thing3:versionName: baz
thing4:versionName: boo
```

then

```
$ for f in thing*; do version+=( "$(grep 'versionName' "$f")" ); done
$ 
$ echo "${version[0]}"
versionName: foo
$ 
$ echo "${version[3]}"
versionName: boo
```